# Unable to run SQL script in Oracle g10 XE

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-xe, sql-scripts

I'm trying to upload and run an SQL script. I can upload it fine, but when when I go to run/edit I just have a red box, and the only button that works is delete.

Google tells me it's a browser issue, and that it will work on IE, but I've tested on:

- Firefox v44.0.2
- Chrome v48
- Edge v25
- IE 11

With no luck. Each one has just given me the same red box.

I know the script itself is correct, it was given to me by my instructor.

[Here's the screen I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVDqx.png)

**Edit:**
Here's the first chunk of the script I'm working with. I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing when it comes to SQL, I'm in an introductory level database course and right now we're just working with preexisting scripts. The whole file is almost 700 lines, but I've gone through and there doesn't seem to be any obvious problem.

```
-- script to create NORTHWOODS database
-- revised 8/17/2002 JM 
-- modified 3/17/2004 LM

-- script to create NORTHWOODS database
-- revised 8/17/2002 JM
-- modified 3/17/2004 LM

DROP TABLE enrollment CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE course_section CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE term CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE course CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE student CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE faculty CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


DROP TABLE LOCATION CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


CREATE TABLE LOCATION (loc_id NUMBER(6),
                       bldg_code VARCHAR2(10),
                                 room VARCHAR2(6),
                                      capacity NUMBER(5),
                                      CONSTRAINT location_loc_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (loc_id));


CREATE TABLE faculty (f_id NUMBER(6), f_last VARCHAR2(30), f_first VARCHAR2(30), f_mi CHAR(1), loc_id NUMBER(5), f_phone VARCHAR2(10), f_rank VARCHAR2(9), f_super NUMBER(6), f_pin NUMBER(4), f_image BLOB, CONSTRAINT faculty_f_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(f_id), CONSTRAINT faculty_loc_id_fk
                      FOREIGN KEY (loc_id) REFERENCES LOCATION(loc_id));


CREATE TABLE student (s_id VARCHAR2(6), s_last VARCHAR2(30), s_first VARCHAR2(30), s_mi CHAR(1), s_address VARCHAR2(25), s_city VARCHAR2(20), s_state CHAR(2), s_zip VARCHAR2(10), s_phone VARCHAR2(10), s_class CHAR(2), s_dob DATE, s_pin NUMBER(4), f_id NUMBER(6), time_enrolled INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH, CONSTRAINT student_s_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (s_id), CONSTRAINT student_f_id_fk
                      FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES faculty(f_id));


CREATE TABLE TERM (term_id NUMBER(6), term_desc VARCHAR2(20), status VARCHAR2(20), start_date DATE, CONSTRAINT term_term_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (term_id), CONSTRAINT term_status_cc CHECK ((status = 'OPEN')
                                                                                                                                                                                       OR (status = 'CLOSED')));


CREATE TABLE COURSE (course_no VARCHAR2(7), course_name VARCHAR2(25), credits NUMBER(2), CONSTRAINT course_course_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(course_no));


CREATE TABLE COURSE_SECTION (c_sec_id NUMBER(6), course_no VARCHAR2(7) CONSTRAINT course_section_courseid_nn NOT NULL, term_id NUMBER(6) CONSTRAINT course_section_termid_nn NOT NULL, sec_num NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT course_section_secnum_nn NOT NULL, f_id NUMBER(6), c_sec_day VARCHAR2(10), c_sec_time DATE, c_sec_duration INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, loc_id NUMBER(6), max_enrl NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT course_section_maxenrl_nn NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT course_section_csec_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_sec_id), CONSTRAINT course_section_cid_fk
                             FOREIGN KEY (course_no) REFERENCES course(course_no), CONSTRAINT course_section_loc_id_fk
                             FOREIGN KEY (loc_id) REFERENCES LOCATION(loc_id), CONSTRAINT course_section_termid_fk
                             FOREIGN KEY (term_id) REFERENCES term(term_id), CONSTRAINT course_section_fid_fk
                             FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES faculty(f_id));


CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT (s_id VARCHAR2(6), c_sec_id NUMBER(6), grade CHAR(1), CONSTRAINT enrollment_pk PRIMARY KEY (s_id, c_sec_id), CONSTRAINT enrollment_sid_fk
                         FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES student(s_id), CONSTRAINT enrollment_csecid_fk
                         FOREIGN KEY (c_sec_id) REFERENCES course_section (c_sec_id));

 ---- inserting into LOCATION table
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it's uploaded fine. Are you losing line breaks, maybe moving the text to/from Windows?

Comment: I've double checked the file and everything seems okay. I've also tried to edit it from within Oracle, but in the script editor has the same red box issue.

Comment: Look at what the screen shot is showing you. Everything is on a single line which has `--` at the start so it's all commentd out. I'd guess it's also too long - not sure what causes it to go red though. Look at the line endings in your file, maybe in a diffrent editor (vim, notepad++, etc.

Comment: Uploaded a snippet of the script I'm working with. It's not all commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. Solved my issue but I have no insight into what went wrong.

Installed Oracle XE on a Win7 virtual machine so I could try an older version of IE. Ran the script on that. Worked perfectly.

For future reference, running the script on IE 8 worked for me